# Are there other "meeting places" for the community here at Writers?

Tags: discussion

I've stumbled across a comment under a question today that made me think. It mentioned meeting on discord to escape the "question-answer" format, that is unfit for ... well, a certain range of topics; from critique request to harmless banter.

So I'm wondering if is there a meeting place that the community here is using somewhat consistently when such needs arise. If there isn't, maybe it would be a good idea to start one (in a writing-group fashion).

Keep in mind that I'm widely ignorant about the in-site chat. I know it exists, but for me it's the place where "all comments and discussions go to die" (joking, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) is sometimes active and sometimes not, but it's the place on this site to go for general discussion, talking about (and sharing) your work, asking for the kinds of advice that don't fit the Q&A format, and so on.  (We used to have a weekly writing challenge where somebody would announce a topic or keywords and everybody would write for 10 minutes and then share.  Time zones make it difficult, but I encourage anybody who wants to organize that again to go for it.)

There's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem in that if there isn't much chatting then people don't visit, but if people don't visit then chatting isn't possible.  Sometimes people watch from the transcript rather than entering the room, so I encourage you to visit and bring up something for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

We had a related question posted today.  I had to look it up to make sure it wasn't from you.

[Where can I post my rough drafts for peer evaluations?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/where-can-i-post-my-rough-drafts-for-peer-evaluations)

I'd like to see something but, when I've gone to chat, I couldn't make immediate sense out of the format.  Maybe I'll try again when my brain cells aren't saturated with smoke (yes, I'm in California).

As for the issue of where to post asking for critiques, the question above had a close flag and I voted to keep it open.  It's a duplicate but the original message was 7 years ago.  So if this community can provide the function, all the better.